# Popup Controller function call in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, popup

I am using this [Popup Dialog service](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/angularjs-popup-dialog/), as it seems to be the popular dialog. I am calling the popup dialog as follows:

```
$scope.upload = function() {
    createDialogService('simpleModal.html', {
      id: 'simpleDialog',
      title: 'Upload Video to save India',
      backdrop: true,
      controller: 'TrafficListController',
      success: {label: 'Success', fn: function() {console.log('Simple modal closed');}}
    }); 
};
```

and my simpleModal.html contains just the following (a form)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<form ng-submit="addNewVideo()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newVid.videoURL" placeholder="Video URL here"> <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newVid.locality" placeholder="locality"> <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newVid.town" placeholder="town"> <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newVid.city" placeholder="city"> <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newVid.pincode" placeholder="Pin Code" value="600015"> <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newVid.time" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm" value="2014-03-20 08:20"> <br/>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Add Video" class="btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
```

But when I click on Submit button in the popup form, it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'videoURL' of undefined` and my `addNewVideo()` looks like this:

```
$scope.addNewVideo = function() {
    var vid = {};
    $log.log($scope);
    vid["videoURL"] = $scope.newVid.videoURL;
    vid["thumbURL"] = $scope.newVid.videoURL;
    vid["uploadedBy"] = "someone";
    vid["analyzedBy"] = "";
    vid["locality"] = $scope.newVid.locality;
    vid["town"] = $scope.newVid.town;
    vid["city"] = $scope.newVid.city;
    vid["pincode"] = $scope.newVid.pincode;
    vid["time"] = $scope.newVid.time;

    var json = JSON.stringify(vid);
}
```

But If I embed the form in the page itself rather than the popup, it works just fine. I am not sure whether the popup uses the same instance of the `TrafficListController` or is creating a new one. Even if it creates a new instance, that specific function `addNewVideo()` doesn't depend upon any other properties / vars of the other instance and supposed to work.

What I am donig wrong? any help?

References:
index.html: https://github.com/GethuGames/Traffic-Violations-Portal/blob/master/index.html
trafficListController.js: https://github.com/GethuGames/Traffic-Violations-Portal/blob/master/trafficListController.js

Comment: please add your controller so I can see what it looks like.

Comment: here it is.. https://github.com/GethuGames/Traffic-Violations-Portal/blob/master/trafficListController.js linked at the bottom of the post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read from `$scope.newVid` on your addVideo function, but it does not exist. Try to initialize this object first.